# How can I activate "save changes" dialogs with my keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys

This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

What I'm used to:
n = no, don't save changes
y = yes, save changes
c = cancel

This was pretty universal in all Windows dialogs, but rarely (if ever?) does it work in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and see the shortcuts.

[image]

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+C as in this case, to `Cancel`.